# Use Keras Model inside TF Object Detection

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection-api

I'm trying to use my Keras model alongside my TF object detection model. But I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: Calling `Model.predict` in graph mode is not supported when the `Model` instance was constructed with eager mode enabled. Please construct your `Model` instance in graph mode or call `Model.predict` with eager mode enabled.
```

It errors on `print(np.around(model1.predict(datatest)))`

I believe it is because with TF object detection I have to run it within

```
with detection_graph.as_default():
  with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=detection_graph) as sess:
```

I'm not trying to run my Keras model in graph mode. Any idea around this?

Answer (score 0):

I had initially loaded the model outside the with statements, but loading within the with statements seems to fix the issue.